# Break points can't be displayed on Spring Source Tool Suite

Tags: java, eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, mylyn

I'm using Mylyn Task Management in Spring Source Tool Suite 2.9. In Breakpoints window, when I click on button "Focus on Active Task", both old and new created Java break points can't be displayed on this window, , except for Javascript break points.

I think this may be a bug of Spring Source Tool, because it works perfect for standard Eclipse. Or may I miss some configuration to make it work? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on here without more info.  Look at your error log and paste any relevant errors here.

Comment: @Andrew Where I can find the tool log files?

Comment: I checked the lastest version of the tool. The issue still exists.

Comment: Go to Window -> Show view -> Other -> Error log